# Avoid duplicate values for certain column in DAX query

Tags: dax

I am using the following statement to get a result table:

```
EVALUATE
(
    CALCULATETABLE
    (
       ADDCOLUMNS (
     'Case',
    "Casenumber", RELATED( 'CaseDetails'[nr]),
       ),
'Case'[Date] <= value(@dateto)     )
)
```

However, I want to only get one record pr casenumber. In SQL I would solve this with a `GROUP BY` statement, but how should I do this in DAX? Case also has a dimkey, so several cases with the same casenumber can have different dimkeys.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
EVALUATE
CALCULATETABLE(
    SUMMARIZE(
        Case
        ,<comma-separated list of fields from Case you want>
        ,"CaseNumber"
        ,RELATED(CaseDetails[nr])
    )
    ,Case[Date] <= VALUE(@dateto)
)
```

SUMMARIZE() takes a table as its first argument, then a comma-separated list of fields from that table and any tables that it is related to where it is on the many side (thus in a star schema, SUMMARIZE()ing the fact table will allow you to refer directly to any dimension table field), followed by a comma-separated list of ,  pairs where  is a quoted field name and  is a scalar value which is evaluated in the row context of the table in the first argument.

If you don't need to rename CaseDetails[nr], then the query would look like this (just for an illustrative example):

```
EVALUATE
CALCULATETABLE(
    SUMMARIZE(
        Case
        ,<comma-separated list of fields from Case you want>
        ,CaseDetails[nr]
    )
    ,Case[Date] <= VALUE(@dateto)
)
```

In such a query, all fields will come through with column headings in the format of 'table'[field], so there is no ambiguity if you have identical field names in multiple related tables.

Edit to address new information in original:

SUMMARIZE(), just like SQL's GROUP BY clause will not eliminate distinct values from the resultset. If there is a field that is a higher cardinality than the field you want to group by, you will always see duplicates.

Is your [DimKey] necessary in the resultset? If yes, then there's no way to decrease the size of your resultset smaller than the number of distinct values of [DimKey].

If [DimKey] is unnecessary, simply omit it from the list of fields in SUMMARIZE().

If you want only a specific [DimKey], e.g. the most recent (assuming it's an IDENTITY field and the max value is the latest), then you can bring it in with another ADDCOLUMNS() wrapped around your current SUMMARIZE():

```
EVALUATE
ADDCOLUMNS(
    SUMMARIZE(
        Case
        ,<comma-separated list of fields from Case except for [DimKey]>
        ,"CaseNumber"
        ,RELATED(CaseDetails[nr])
    )
    ,"MaxDimKey"
    ,CALCULATE(MAX(Case[DimKey]))
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is the list on the form 'Case'[Details], 'Case'[Responsible], etc.., etc

Comment: I tried this, It seems like the duplicate CaseDetails are still there, sadly. Check up first post, I've updated with some details.